# Unable to read and write Japanese folder structure in Tomcat 7, but it works for a Docker container

Tags: java, character-encoding, tomcat7, cjk

Getting a `FileNotFoundException` while reading a Japanese folder structer from a Tomcat 7 web application. But it's working in a Docker container and direct java console execution.

Both Docker and normal tomcat7 setup and configurations are the same.

We have done following configurations:

1. Tomcat Server `server.xml` - In Connector tag added `URIEncoding` attribute as:

   ```xml
   <Connector port="8080"
              protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
              connectionTimeout="20000" 
              redirectPort="8443"
              URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
   ```
2. `catalina.sh` - added following:

   ```bash
   export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server \
      -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit \
      -Djava.awt.headless=true \
      -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 \
      -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

   export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Dfile.encoding='UTF-8'"`
   ```
3. Executed the following command to change the server language:

   ```bash
   export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
   ```

Comment: Tomcat On Windows ?

Comment: Tomcat on centos7

Comment: Japanese Folder: /data/修繕管理/
The docker image is locally created as per our environment setup.
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade Tomcat7 to tomcat9 or Tomcat7.0.109.
The support is not available in Tomcat7 Early versions

Comment: Upgraded to Tomcat7.0.109 and now its Working